# Does the Google BigQuery ML automatically makes the time series data stationary?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, time-series, auto, arima

So I am a newbie to Google BigQuery ML and was wondering if the auto.arima automatically makes my time series data stationary ?

Suppose, I have a data that is not stationary and if I give the data as is to the auto arima model using Google BigQuery ML, will it first makes my data stationary before taking it as input ?

Answer (score 0):

but that's part of the modeling procedure

From the documentation that explains [What's inside a BigQuery ML time series model](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-time-series#whats_inside_a_time_series_model), it does appear that [auto.ARIMA](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html) will make the data stationary.

However, I would not expect it to alter the source data table; it won't make that stationary, but in the course of building candidate models it may alter the input data prior to actual model fitting (transforms; e.g. box-cox, make stationary, etc.)